# Mutexes do not seem to lock the Resources

Tags: go, mutex, goroutine

I want that whenever there is switch on the file, My go routine reads from the new file. and for that I am using Mutexes to do so. But the output does not seem to be as expected. In f1.txt I have `hello` and in f2.txt I have `world`. And I am switching between these two files.

```
type Root struct {
    File *os.File
    sync.RWMutex
}

func main() {
    startWorker()
}
func startTask(root *Root) {
    interval := 1 * time.Second
    ticker := time.NewTicker(interval)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    i := 0
    for {
        go func(i int, root *Root) {
            root.RLock()
            defer root.RUnlock()
            content, _ := io.ReadAll(root.File)
            fmt.Printf("go routine %v is reading data %s\n", i, content)
        }(i, root)
        i++
        <-ticker.C
    }
}
func startWorker() {

    interval := 4 * time.Second
    ticker := time.NewTicker(interval)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    f1 := "concurrent/1/f1.txt"
    f2 := "concurrent/2/f2.txt"

    f := f1
    file, _ := os.Open(f)
    root := &Root{File: file}

    go startTask(root)
    for {
        root.Lock()
        if f == f2 {
            f = f1
        } else {
            f = f2
        }
        root.File.Close()
        file, _ := os.Open(f)
        root.File = file
        root.Unlock()
        <-ticker.C
    }
}
```

The output seem to be as follows

```
go routine 0 is reading data world
go routine 1 is reading data 
go routine 2 is reading data 
go routine 3 is reading data 
go routine 4 is reading data hello
go routine 5 is reading data 
go routine 6 is reading data 
go routine 7 is reading data 
go routine 8 is reading data world
go routine 9 is reading data
```

Comment: First of all, don't ignore errors. Then try again.

Comment: The output remains same even after handling the error

Comment: Please update in your question to show code that properly handle errors.

Comment: The output shown in the question looks like the result from `io.ReadAll` is the zero-value, likely from an error reading. Inspecting that would be required to know what's going on in better detail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `io.ReadAll(root.File)` reads to the end of the file and subsequent reads come up empty.  To ensure that the file contents is read, seek to the beginning of the file before reading.

Because the state of the file is modified when reading (the seek position is changed) and the reading goroutines can run concurrently in theory, the reader should use a write lock.

```
    go func(i int, root *Root) {
        root.Lock()
        defer root.Unlock()
        root.File.Seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        content, _ := io.ReadAll(root.File)
        fmt.Printf("go routine %v is reading data %s\n", i, content)
    }(i, root)
```

[Try it on the Go Playground!](https://go.dev/play/p/modI9YNzHkp).